# How to publish/install VS Code extensions via GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to publish/install VS Code extensions via `github.com` instead using of `dev.azure.com`?

I assume the steps would look like:

```
git clone 'https://github.com/abc/xyz.git'
vsce package
git add -A && git commit -m 'initialized vscode extension'
git push origin
```

and then in VS Code there would be some option to install a plugin from `https://github.com/abc/xyz.git`

is this possible?

Comment: Note, I would hope the technique to publish to github would be similar to npmjs.org

Comment: Many of VS Code users are not web developers, so you shouldn't expect a mechanism used by NPM can work for that audience.

Comment: Not really a VSCode users thing, more like VSCode Extensions users thing, big differences. The end user won't necessary know where an extension is published.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess removing the vsce tag was the right thing to do

Answer (score 1):

VS Code can install a vsix package (which is actually a zip), but that must be in the local file system. You cannot specify a URL as source.

Comment: Yeah I guess use a git clone nearby and symlink it somewhere important

Comment: If you could link to some documentation that describes where to put the vsix package, then I can accept this answer

Comment: I added an answer that I think is more befitting OP, requesting feedback

Comment: I doubt there is any documentation about this specific fact. IMO it's self evident. There's the option to install a vsix by selecting a file, so it's limited to whatever you can present in the file system. Sure with some script fu you can mount something external into your file system and use that, but that's complete different matter.

Comment: I don't know what kind of headspace you're in but barring strace or dtrace and a lot of guesswork  how would you know that "$HOME/.vscode/extensions" is the right path without google? and google would take you here or similar. Furthermore, this shows that a softlink works, occasionally they aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

On a macOS/Linux machine, you can do this:

1. assume your VS Code extension is hosted at `https://github.com/abc/xyz.git`
2. `git clone 'https://github.com/abc/xyz.git'`
3. `ln -s "$PWD/xyz" "$HOME/.vscode/extensions/xyz"`  (create a softlink)

When you open VS Code, if you look in installed extensions, it will show your extension. No need to compile anything to vsix, it runs your JavaScript. In other words, create your git repo that represents your VS Code extension, clone it locally, and symlink that folder to `~/.vscode/extensions/xyz`. I am sure on Windows that the concept is the same.

Comment: Have follwed the steps on Linux, but this doesn't work for me. The extension is visible in ~/.vscode/extensions/xyz but not seen in VSCode under extensions. In .../xyz is also package.json but still not working... also made sure that all privileges are granted